# Google Admin SDK Directory Users List returns group as a user

Tags: google-api, google-apps, google-admin-sdk, google-directory-api

I'm using the Admin SDK Directory api to read users out of a domain. Everything works fine except for the fact that the `users.list` is returning groups as part of that list. While not devastating it causes some confusion when users are using my app.

The method in question can be found here. 
https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/users/list

I don't even use the scopes for groups. I have authorization for the `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/admin.directory.user.readonly` scope only, not any related to groups.

Here is an example of a user entry returned (with names and such obviously changed):

```
{
  "kind": "admin#directory#user",
  "id": "someId",
  "etag": "\"An etag\"",
  "primaryEmail": "group@domain.com",
  "isAdmin": false,
  "isDelegatedAdmin": false,
  "lastLoginTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "creationTime": "1970-01-01T00:00:00.000Z",
  "agreedToTerms": false,
  "suspended": false,
  "changePasswordAtNextLogin": false,
  "ipWhitelisted": false,
  "emails": [
    {
    "address": "group@domain.com",
    "primary": true
    }
  ],
  "customerId": "customer",
  "orgUnitPath": "/",
  "isMailboxSetup": true,
  "includeInGlobalAddressList": true
}
```

Comment: Is this happening for all groups in your domain or just some of them?

Comment: @EricKoleda just some of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due to a bug in the API. This bug is being tracked on the Google Apps APIs Issue Tracker:

https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=3654

Comment: This issue should now be fixed.

Comment: I'll test and let you know.